# Deserialization of ObservableCollection kills events?

Tags: c#, events, observablecollection

I have an ObservableCollection that is typeof UITestCaseElement:

```
public ObservableCollection<UITestCaseElement> TestCases = new ObservableCollection<UITestCaseElement>();

public class UITestCaseElement : IDisposable
{
    public int UniqueIdentifier { get; set; }
    public string TestCaseName { get; set; }
    public string TestCaseDescription { get; set; }

    public int RepeatCount { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore] 
    public int NumOfRuntimes { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public Testcases.AbstractTestCase TestObject { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public OMS4Driver.DeviceObject DeviceObject { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public OMS4Driver.ClientObject ClientObject { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public OMS4Driver.Generic.CameraSelect SelectedCamera { get; set; }

    public void Dispose() { }
}
```

And here's the way I open the generated XML:

```
private void mnuLoadConfig_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<UITestCaseElement>));

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\test.xml"))
    {
        _tcMngr.TestCases = (System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<UITestCaseElement>)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }

}
```

If the collection is beeing changed, it fires an event to the main form starting some handling on the UI.

Everything works fine (usage, export) but as soon as I de-serialize the xml file and copy back the ObservableCollection, the ObservableCollection events won't be fired anymore. If I debug the TestCases Instance, then all changes can be found within this collection.

Why?

Thank you very much!

## Update:

I overwrite the complete collection and thus there's no delegate for the events pointing to my event handler anymore. That's stupid somehow. Thanks @all for you help.

Answer (score 2):

That is simply because you replace the entire collection. Those events are not registered on the new instance, created on calling `Deserialize`. (De)serialization does only serialize the data, not the events.

I would suggest to clear the current collection and add all items from the deserialized collection to it.

```
var newCollection = (ObservableCollection<UITestCaseElement>)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

_tcMngr.TestCases.Clear();

foreach (var item in newCollection)
{
    _tcMngr.TestCases.Add(item);
}
```

In this way, the original `_tcMngr.TestCases` stays intact, including all of its event handlers.

Comment: That means, that the Serializer not only inserts the new items but overwrites even delegates of the collection even though there's no content in the XML file?

Comment: Well, you create a new collection, which totally replace the other one. It doesn't overwrite anything, it just starts over again.

Comment: Ohhh s*** you're right! That was stupid! ... I suppose it's time for lunch!

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior, when you serialize your `ObservableCollection`, **all the event handlers are not serialized**. It's problematic if it's possible because these are addresses in memory. Everytime we run the application, these addresses are not the same.

That's why de-serializing does not get it back to the original state.

Answer (score 1):

You're replacing the collection here

```
 _tcMngr.TestCases = (System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<UITestCaseElement>)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

Trying clearing your current collection and add new items.

Comment: yeah, saw after posting, slow inet @ d airport

Comment: No problem :). Enjoy your flight.